# Trigger checkbox action using CSS

Tags: css, sass

This is the HTML structure

```
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">About US</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Services</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Contact</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item"><span>NEW</span></a>
      </div>
```

How do I hide the the `menu` div when #toggle is checked? I'm looking for a way to do this in css itself.

This is what I tried so far. But it doesn't work because the `+` is a adjacent sibling selector. It will work if I move the checkbox out from the `nav-bar` div. Is there a way to achieve this while keeping the same HTML structure?

```
#toggle{
  &:checked + .menu{
    //do stuff;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it is not possible with that HTML structure.

Comment: Your checkbox and your menu need to both be children of the same parent, i.e. your menu should immediately follow the checkbox element see: https://jsfiddle.net/76sv03w1/